# Windows Phone 8 Emulator error, Hyper-V components not running, Windows 2012R2 hosted in AWS EC2

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hyper-v

I am trying to run the windows phone emulator in AWS EC2.
But could not succeed. I have setup everything required to run the emulator.

I get the error mentioned below. Anybody successful in running Windows phone emulator with AWS EC2 instance?

[image]

Comment: do you have vmware workstation on your system if you have one feature used by vmware workstation and hyper-v can not use that or that's problem for io check [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/244617/en-us)

Comment: I have created a VM in AWS and trying to configure from AWS EC2.